# Why this alertdialog size work on some devices and not work on some devices?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-windowmanager

### What I want is :

when a user press button I want to alertdialog which I want is top right. I did something and it works as what I want but on some devices it does not work as I want. I mean it its size is wrong and when I click outside the alertdialog does not disappear , I want it disappear when I click outside.

### My Code :

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
 builder.setTitle("");
 builder.setCancelable(true);
 builder.setItems(items , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
         switch (item) {
         case 0: 
             AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                     MainActivity.this);  
                // set title 
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(areusure);
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage(clicktologout)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton( yes,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                     //something
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton(no_,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                        alertDialog.show(); 

                 break;
             case 1:
                 try { 
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,tutorial.class);            
                     startActivity(myIntent); 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                            feedus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                               toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                               toast.show();                
                }
                 break;
             case 2:   
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,about.class);               
                 startActivity(myIntent); 
                 break;
         }
     }
 });
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 alert.setCancelable(true);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = alert.getWindow().getAttributes();
     wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT; 
 alert.show();
 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
 lp.copyFrom(alert.getWindow().getAttributes());
 int value_y = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
            (float) 42, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

 int value_x = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
            (float) 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


 lp.width = 500; 
 lp.height = 500;
 lp.x=-value_x;
 lp.y=value_y;
 alert.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

**expected image** and **wrong image**:

[image] [image]

Comment: You need to override the device's parent dialog theme with a dialog theme of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `AlertDialog` and assigning static dimensions and X|Y references on screen, I would suggest you to make use of [`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) which is available in API-11 and above. As for older APIs, you may use [support-v7 library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html).

For example and more info, read [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/working-with-androids-popupmenu-class/) and [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example).

Moreover, if the dropdown menu is supposed to be anchored from ActionBar, then I would suggest you to stick with the standard **menu/group/item** implementation rather than going the hard way.

Comment: thanks for answer, how can I implement **menu/group/item** this?

Comment: [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/) is a good tutorial to start with.

Comment: But I did not use action bar. I use linearlayout and make it custom so that example is not for me, so can I override the device's parent dialog theme?

Comment: then stick with popupmenu

Comment: click on the links I've included in my answer